# Implementar un codigo que pone una imagen tomada por cámara en un imageview a otro codigo que muestra opciones en un recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, cámara

tengo un código dónde primero revisa que tengamos los permisos de write external y el de camara, en el layout tengo un imageview, y al darle click se abre la cámara, tomamos una foto, se guarda y regresamos al layout y en el imageview se ve la imágen que acabamos de tomar, el código funciona bien, aquí lo dejo para que lo puedan ver:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 1000;
private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE = 1001;
ImageView foto;
Uri foto_uri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    foto = findViewById(R.id.iv_main_foto);

    foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checarPermisos();
        }
    });
}

private void checarPermisos() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            String[] permission = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE);
        } else {
            openCamera();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_CODE: {
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openCamera();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permisos denegados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void openCamera() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,"Nueva foto");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Desde la camara");
    foto_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, foto_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        foto.setImageURI(foto_uri);
    }
}
```

}

Por otra parte en otra aplicación tengo un recycler view donde con un adapter obtengo todas las opciones de una base de datos con volley y por cada opción me genera un renglón con un image view y un text view donde se pone el nombre, esa parte funciona, al darle click en el imageview creo un toast donde me dice que estoy tocando la imagen y el nombre de la opción, lo que quiero lograr es implementar el primer código a éste segundo, pero al momento del adapter me ha costado trabajo intentar acceder al imageview de cada opción desde el adapter, aquí dejo el adapter para que puedan verlo, lo que quisiera es que al darle click en la imagen de la opción se abra la cámara y se sustituya por la imagen que tomas y poder hacerlo para poner imagen en cada opción.

Aquí esta el código del adapter:

```
public class OpcionesFotoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OpcionesFotoAdapter.OpcionesFotoViewHolder>{

private Context mCtx;
private List<OpcionesFotoClass> opcionesfotoList;

public OpcionesFotoAdapter(Context mCtx, List<OpcionesFotoClass> opcionesfotoList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.opcionesfotoList = opcionesfotoList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public OpcionesFotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemopcionfotos, null);
    return new OpcionesFotoViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final OpcionesFotoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tituloOpcion.setText(opcionesfotoList.get(position).getTituloOpcion());

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int pos) {
            Toast.makeText(mCtx,"You're clicking the imageview!" + opcionesfotoList.get(position).getTituloOpcion(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return opcionesfotoList.size();
}


public class OpcionesFotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView tituloOpcion;
    ImageView foto;

    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public OpcionesFotoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tituloOpcion = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombreOpcionFoto);
        foto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_fotoOpcion);

        foto.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener ic) {
        this.itemClickListener = ic;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
    }
}
interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int pos);
}
```

}

Gracias y quedo pendiente a respuestas.

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es que con onItemClick de tu adapter llamas a un activity y con ese saques la foto, el unico que debes tener cuidado es con los ciclos del vida del activity, despues de sacar la foto, deberia ir al MainActivity y cargar el resultado en el metodo onResume(), el activity que saca la foto debe ser declarado en el manifest como singleTask, de todas forma valida eso con la documentacion https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode

Comment: yo estoy queriendo hacer exactamente eso también pero no me sale. Pudiste encontrar una forma?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es ponerle a tu adapter un insertToIndex y un get list:

```
 public void insertToIndex(int index,OpcionesFotoClass obj){
        
            opcionesfotoList.add(index,obj);
            notifyItemInserted(index);
        
    };
  public List<OpcionesFotoClass> getList(){
            
             return opcionesfotoList:
            
        };
```

En tu actividad (tiene que ser el listener) manejas el click para abrir la camara y el resultado que se pasara a tu adapter y se notificara entonces obtendras la uri en la funcion bindViewHolder ya actualizada de tu adapter ahí ya tendrás la uri:

```
  Int posicionActual = 0;
   OpcionesFotoClass itemOld;
    public void onItemClick(View view, int pos){
        posicionActual = pos;
         itemOld = adapter.getList().get(pos);
         checarPermisos();
    }:


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        itemOld.imageUri = foto_uri
        adapter.getList().removeAt(pos);
        adapter.insertToIndex(posicionActual,itemOld)
    }
}
```